# Drawn triangle path leaves a trace

Tags: android

class Triangle

```
public class Triangle extends View {
    private int x, y;
    private int _xDelta, _yDelta;
    private Point triangleA = new Point();
    private Point triangleB = new Point();
    private Point triangleC = new Point();
    public static Path trianglePath = new Path();
    private Paint paintTriangle = new Paint();

    public Triangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public Triangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public Triangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttyr) {
        paintTriangle.setColor(Color.RED);
        paintTriangle.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            _xDelta = X - x;
            _yDelta = Y - y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = X - _xDelta;
            y = Y - _yDelta;
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        triangleA.set(x - 100 - 10, y + 100 + 10);
        triangleB.set(x, y - 100 - 10);
        triangleC.set(x + 100 + 10, y + 100 + 10);
        trianglePath.moveTo(triangleA.x, triangleA.y);
        trianglePath.lineTo(triangleB.x, triangleB.y);
        trianglePath.lineTo(triangleC.x, triangleC.y);
        trianglePath.lineTo(triangleA.x, triangleA.y);
        trianglePath.close();
        canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, paintTriangle);

        invalidate();
    }

}
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.squaremovement.MainActivity" >

<com.example.squaremovement.Triangle
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The triangle leaves a trace when it moves, so how can I remove it and only leave the new position. Or is there another solution?
This is only a test from my main application in which I have to see if this path contains another path.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the canvas before drawing your triangle:

```
canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
```

Comment: its not working the only thing it does is make the background black

Comment: At list i just figured out how to paint :D

Answer (score 0):

i cind of figure it out but i can not use it like that because i need to use the path in another view to see if it contains another path by using bounds or something like that

I just created the Path in ondraw like this

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    triangleA.set(x - 100 - 10, y + 100 + 10);
    triangleB.set(x, y - 100 - 10);
    triangleC.set(x + 100 + 10, y + 100 + 10);
    Path trianglePath = new Path();

    trianglePath.moveTo(triangleA.x, triangleA.y);
    trianglePath.lineTo(triangleB.x, triangleB.y);
    trianglePath.lineTo(triangleC.x, triangleC.y);
    trianglePath.lineTo(triangleA.x, triangleA.y);
    trianglePath.close();

    canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, paintTriangle);

}
```